# Jquery text overlay on thumbnail onhover in list

Tags: jquery, text, overlay, onhover

How can I have text appear when hovering a thumbnail image - I've found some tutorials but I need it to work in a list structure like below. Preferably as an additional li or caption.

Site for reference is here: http://owenmyers.co.uk/TESTING/

```
 #item {
position:absolute;
top:117px;
width:711px;
height:100%;
left:150px;
z-index:1;
}
.item {
    margin:0px;
}
.item.first {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.item img {
    opacity:0;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.item ul {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:721px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    z-index:5;
}
.item ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    height:115px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<div id="item" class="item">
<ul style="margin-top:0px;">
<li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="img/holderthumb.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/holderthumb.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/holderthumb.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/holderthumb.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each image you should add the attribute `alt`. For instance 
`<img src="img/holderthumb.jpg" alt="Description Here"/>`
You could also do the Title Attribute 
`<img src="img/holderthumb.jpg" title="Description Here"/>`

Once you have that done, you can create a simple script that grabs those attributes (either or) and display those. For instance here's an example

```
$("img#id").hover(
function(){
    var desc = $(this).attr("title"); //Or $(this).attr("alt");
    $("divthatcontainstext").html(desc); //Puts attribute text into div that needs text
}, //Hover Encompasses Mouse on and Mouse off into one function
function(){
    $("divthatcontainstext").html(""); //Clears div with text
});
```

I think that was the basis of your question. Make sure that the code is wrapper in either `$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$(function(){});`

Comment: Don't seem to be able to make it work - see my code here: 
http://owenmyers.co.uk/TESTING/

Getting this error (not sure it's directly related?) 
"event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future."

Comment: That error is related to a function that you have that would be tracking the position of the mouse... I don't have that function in use in my code. However that error is a warning, and shouldn't actually effect the functioning of the code